# How to update data without changes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to insert the document in MongoDB and it's successfully inserted into the collection. If I updated the same document again without any changes it's getting updated and getting a success message as a response.

**Insert document**

```
{
    "user_full_name": "user123",
    "user_email": "google123@techardors.com",
    "user_phone": "9999989998"
}
```

**update document**

```
{
    "user_full_name": "user123",
    "user_email": "google123@techardors.com",
    "user_phone": "9999989998"
}
```

**I got output**

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

**Expected output**

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

Comment: [hari-prasanth], what is the problem you are trying to solve here? Do you want to restrict the update if there is no change?

Comment: @Ravi  Sorry for all my code is mistake.I corrected its working fine

Comment: @ersnh Sorry  my code is mistake.I corrected its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Though you have used the same content to update the document, Internally MongoDB never compares the records like old data with new data. MongoDB simply replaces old data with new data. So, It will be considered as Updated.

Comment: but I cant change any data .I want nModified :0 how to acheive it.

Comment: Maybe I will give some example like, Let say I have inserted 'ABC'  then again I am updating again with 'ABC' by replacing old 'ABC'. So MongoDB will not do like  'ABC' == 'ABC'  are the same and will not skip the update. Instead of that simply replace the data even though the same data exist.